# Execute focus() method on lightning:tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components

What is the correct way of executing focus method() on the beta component lightning

[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_tab.htm) says there is `focus(): Sets the focus on the element.`

Is there specific way to execute it? I tried via document.find().focus(). Doesn't throw an error, but I suspect it executes browser-native focus() event.

To add to complexity (I should probably open a separate question), document.find() doesn't work with tabs created via aura:iteration:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.sidebar}" var="i">
    <lightning:tab onactive="{! c.handleActive }" label="{!i.label}" aura:id="{!i.name}" id="{!i.name}" />
  </aura:iteration>
```

However, for the purpose of this experiment, I did try with hardcoded references.

Comment: To call `focus()` you would use `component.find('AURA_ID').focus()`. Also, judging by your comment about using hardcoded references I'd assume you're aware, but the `aura:id` attribute doesn't support expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be asking the wrong question. If you want to select a specific *tab*, use the selectedTabId of the lightning:tabset. From there, you can specify the appropriate tab to select. Please note that aura:id does not accept merge fields, so you should be using "id" instead.

Here's a fully contained example that demonstrates how you can do this. As you can see, Tab 2 will be selected by default.

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="selectedTabId" type="String" default="Tab2" />
    <aura:attribute name="tabs" type="Object[]" default="[{label:'Tab 1',id:'Tab1'},{label:'Tab 2',id:'Tab2'},{label:'Tab 3',id:'Tab3'}]" />
    <lightning:tabset selectedTabId="{!v.selectedTabId}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.tabs}" var="tab">
            <lightning:tab label="{!tab.label}" title="{!tab.label}" id="{!tab.id}">
                {!tab.label} Content
            </lightning:tab>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:tabset>
</aura:application>
```

If you want to programmatically specify the new tab to use, simply set `selectedTabId` and it will happen automatically.

Comment: That's nice and much simpler than I've anticipated. Sorry I cannot validate it as I've moved to vertical navigation. Speaking of which, perhaps there is a way to make tabs vertical? :D

Comment: @dzh Nope. The design is reactive, so it adjusts to all styles of displays. Unfortunately, it doesn't come in a vertical flavor.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question is incorrect. sfdcfox said correct.

I can't see any **focus()** method in the documentation to set focus of **lightning:tab**. Infact there is an attribute called as **onfocus**

**onfocus** - The action triggered when the element receives focus.

So as sfdcfox shared the code snipped that will work perfectly.

And yes **aura:id** doesn't take any expressions in it, you need to write hard coded ID there

Sample code to set focus on a particular tab -

```
<lightning:tabset selectedTabId="sampleTab">
    <lightning:tab label="Sample" title="Title" id="sampleTab">
        Some Content
    </lightning:tab>
    <lightning:tab label="Sample 2" title="Title 2" id="sample2Tab">
        Some Other Content
    </lightning:tab>
</lightning:tabset>
```